# List object not callable

Tags: python

I have an assignment to create a slot machine. I'm trying to write the loop that will spin the machine, but it keeps saying my list isn't callable.

Here's where I am having the issue:

```
wheel1 = ['Candy','Ghost','Pumpkin','Cat','Zombie','Witch','Witch','Cat','Ghost','Candy']
wheel2 = ['Candy','Ghost','Pumpkin','Cat','Zombie','Witch','Cat','Pumpkin','Ghost','Candy']
wheel3 = ['Candy','Ghost','Pumpkin','Cat','Zombie','Witch','Pumpkin','Candy','Candy','Ghost']

#loop to spin
i = 0

while i < 500:
    spin1 = random.randint(0,9)
    spin2 = random.randint(0,9)
    spin3 = random.randint(0,9)
    print(str[wheel1(spin1)])
    i += 1
```

I figured maybe the brackets were in the wrong space, but if I place them anywhere else I get a syntax error.

Comment: `wheel1` is a list and you access list elements using the bracket (operator). so it should be `wheel1[spin1]` instead of `wheel1(spin1)`. And the call to `str` should be using parentheses, so your print statement should be `print(str(wheel1[spin1]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update line with `print(str[wheel1(spin1)])` to `print(str(wheel1[spin1]))`.

The issue is when you do `wheel1()`, python treats that as function and try to call the function. But since you are having `list` and want to access the value, the syntax is `wheel1[i]` where `i` is the index you want to access.

Also, you are doing `str[..]`, but instead it should be `str(..)` due to the same reason as mention above.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Fixed it perfectly.